# ASP MVC Razor View doesn't want to show @Html.TextBoxFor value from the model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

my razor view is accepting a model ... and I have this code in it ..

```
@{
    var my_value = "wth";
    if (Model.app != null)
    { my_value = Model.app.name; }
}

@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.app.name, new { @Value = my_value })
```

shows 'wth' when the model isn't null ... did some debugging to see if my_value is set properly ... hmmm

Edit:

Thank you for the comments.

A bit new to ASP MVC. Some background to what I am trying to do:

1. I have a main view, Main.cshtml, which shows records. Each record can be edited by clicking glyphicon.
2. JS code grabs the record_id and makes Ajax call to Application Controller / editApp action.
3. I have a partial, _EditApplication.cshtml, within Main.cshtml, to show my tabbed jQuery UI dialog. And also uses _AddAppForm.cshtml partial that takes a Model to be shown in the data fields.

   .... I think this is where my problem is (among others lol)... I am calling the partial (_EditApplication.cshtml) in the main view ... and I am returning the same partial in my Controller Action with an associated model.

Code:

Main.cshmtl

```
@{ AppDBServer this_ads = new AppDBServer(); }
@Html.Partial("_EditApplication", this_ads)

<div id=@app.app_id.ToString() class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil btn_edit_app" aria-hidden="true" style="color:blue; cursor:pointer"></div>
```

JS code in Main.cshtml

```
    $('.btn_edit_app').click(function () {
        var app_to_edit = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Application/editApp',
            contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
            data: { app_id: app_to_edit},
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (result) {},
        });
        $('#edit_tabs').tabs({ active: 0 });
        $('#edit_dialog').dialog({ width: 700, height: 400 });
    });
```

_EditApplication.cshtml - Partial

```
@using NameSpace.Models
@model AppDBServer

<div id="edit_dialog" title="Edit Application" style="display: none">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("saveApps", "Application", new { isNew = false }))    {
        <div id="edit_tabs">
            <ul><li><a href="#edit_application">Application</a></li></ul>
                @Html.Partial("_AddAppForm", @Model)
        </div>
}
</div>
```

Application Controller - Action: editApp

```
namespace SHS_Connect.Controllers
{
    public class ApplicationController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult editApp(int app_id)
            {
                AppDBServer ads = new AppDBServer();
                ads = findADS(app_id);
                return PartialView("_EditApplication", ads);
            }
    }
}
```

_AddAppForm.cshmtl - Partial used in _EditApplication.cshtml

```
@using NameSpace.Models
@model AppDBServer

<div id="application">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(a => a.app.name)

        @{
            var my_value = "wth";
            if (Model.app != null)
            { my_value = Model.app.name; }
        }
        @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.app.name, new { @Value = my_value })
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are doing, marking down question for pure lack of understanding

Comment: Do not attempt to set the `value` attribute when using the `HtmlHelper` methods. You set the value of the property in the GET method before you pass the model to the view.

Comment: That's what I normally do ... I have a bad design problem I am thinking .. I am using the same partial in my Main.cshtml and returning that same partial with the model and associated values from the db. In the Main, partial just takes an empty model ... so when I go to display.. I say, if it's null, then just show an empty field. 

Why I am using same Partials:

- If I don't include the partial in Main.cshtml, my jQuery dialog w/tabs doesn't popup.

- I also need the tabs to show model data.

Answer (score 1):

So, yea, I figure it out ... in case someone gets stuck like this ... changes to make:

Main.cshmtl:

adding the partial here doesn't work, have to replace it with a div tag w/id that will contain the partial ...

```
<div id="div_editapp_dialog"></div>
```

JS Code in Main.cshtml:

The success function should populate the div and get the tabs / dialog going.

```
success: function (result) {
                    $('#div_editapp_dialog').html(result);
                    $('#edit_tabs').tabs({ active: 0 });
                    $('#edit_dialog').dialog({ width: 700, height: 400 });
                }
```

No change to _EditApplication.cshtml and the Controller.

Clean up _AddAppForm.cshmtl ...

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(a => a.app.name)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.app.name)
</div>
```